# android custom flag

Tags: android, flags

I am currently work on an application which has a service and an activity. They change some file and I want to save which one of them made the last change. Is there anyway else than writing to file again?
Can I create a custom flag like the ones already defined in android like RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION?

**EDIT :**  I do not want to use SharedPreferences, what I really want to learn is to create custom flags in OS if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Android SharedPreferences to store which of the file made the last change. [Here](http://www.rominirani.com/android-preferences-tutorial/) is the tutorial to get you started on SharedPreferences.

Comment: Thanks that's a way to do that, however I already know what SharedPreferences meet my need. But what I really want is to create a custom flag. Is that possible?

Comment: I think it is better to use extra capability of intent. On the other hand, you must use put extra for attaching a boolean  or some things  else to the intent which starts service.